# What is the fastest way to write to a db table from R?

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, ssis

I have a data table in R with 1.5M rows. I want to export this to a MS SQL db table.

I know I can do it this way:

```
dbWriteTable(conn,"benefit_custom.Trial_set",trial_set )
```

But its very slow.

The other option I've tried is to write to a flat file and then create an SSIS pkg to transfer it to the db. This is not a problem, but the issue is that I have string and numeric data in my data table, and when R writes to the file, everything is varchar and is enclosed within quotes.

```
FileLocation <-"\\Benefit_Analysis_Input.dat"

 FileName<- paste( bcpWorkspace,FileLocation,sep = "") 

write.table(trial_set,file =FileName,append = FALSE, sep = "\t",col.names = T, row.names = F)
```

The 1st method preserves the data types like I want to, but the performance is very bad. Does anyone have anything else I can try?

So I guess the data types cant be preserved if I'm writing to a flat file, so I have to go with choosing the data types when I'm importing the flat file into the db

Comment: I'm still pretty new to R, can you point me to the SQL Server implementation for `dbWriteTable`? Thus far, all I see is mysql

Comment: Does it need to stay within the confines of R or would an external script be acceptable?  Perl (or pick your favorite language) could reprocess a CSV file very quickly...

Comment: I'm not sure what you want exactly.. How do I get that?

Comment: @abiessu: I guess I could be open to trying that. How do you suggest I proceed?

Comment: Don't know much about R, but it looks like `write.csv()` accepts an argument that will not quote the fields? http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/datasets/R/html/base/html/write.table.html

Comment: Look at where those rows in your datatable came from.  Maybe your entire approach can be improved upon.

Comment: In general, R will only quote values when writing to file if they exist in R as character or factor. And as mentioned, that behavior will be controlled by arguments in `write.table`. As for @billinkc's question, if they are writing to SQL Server the OP is most likely using RODBC.

Comment: It sounds like there are better approaches than middle-man processing.  But looping through one file's lines and outputting to a second file is quick and easy to implement, with a transform like `@items = split('","', $line); foreach @items[1,3,7] { $_ = '"' . $_ . '"'; } $newline = join(',', @items);`  The `[1,3,7]` slice is a randomly-chosen selection of the columns that might still need quote characters.

Comment: you don't need an SSIS package to transfer into the database, you could just do an import from flat file and choose what data type each column of your flat file is.

Comment: @rhealitycheck: I want to automate this process, so I need as less manual intervention as possible

Comment: But getting back to the better approach, consider using `write.table(trial_set,file =FileName,append = FALSE, quote = [1 3 7], sep = "\t",col.names = T, row.names = F)` (I'm not at all sure how to write a numeric vector in R, but that's the gist of it I think...)

Comment: I'm not seeing a dbWriteTable https://gist.github.com/billinkc/70f1d64418e7dd813f02 I've installed RODBC and DBI. What else would I be missing?

Comment: @billinkc: You're looking for RJDBC

Comment: When using an intermediary (a flat file), what takes longer - writing the filing or importing it? Note you can use BCP.EXE (a sql server tool) to import a flat file and there  are many optimisations you can make. Values in quotes shouldn't be too much of a problem to automate, you'll just need to experiment.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question: the fastest seems to be [rsqlserver](https://github.com/agstudy/rsqlserver)

As of now I know about:

- [rsqlserver](https://github.com/agstudy/rsqlserver): Using *System.Data.SqlClient* drivers, only on win OS
- [RSQLServer](https://github.com/imanuelcostigan/RSQLServer): Using java drivers to SQLserver from any OS using `RJDBC`
- [RODBC](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html): using ODBC drivers, easy setup only on win OS

Still microsoft sql server looks to be quite poorly supported from the R session perspective.

Here is interesting benchmark by rsqlserver project: https://github.com/agstudy/rsqlserver/wiki/benchmarking

Also important to note related to `rsqlserver`: **A linux version using mono is planned.**

Finally, my recent presentation on [Data Warehousing with R](https://cdn.rawgit.com/jangorecki/jangorecki.github.io/master/_posts/Data-Warehousing-with-R.html) covers DBI, RJDBC, RODBC examples.

Answer (score -1):

I think @rhealitycheck is on the right track - I would use the SQL Import and Export Data wizard to generate an SSIS package.  I would save it and customize it later, for example adding an upstream Execute Process Task to call R and write the text file out.

The performance and flexibility of this solution is hard to beat.

Comment: But what about preserving data types? I know using this is faster, but I dont want everything to be varchar

Comment: Option 1. during the Import Wizard, at the Select Source Tables step, use the Edit Mappings window to set datatypes.  Option 2. save the SSIS package from the Import Wizard, then edit it using BIDS/Visual Studio.